# Facing issues while taking input from an android app to a Google sheet and using onChange trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am taking student attendance using an Android app which fills a Google Sheet.

There are various fields coming from the app such as timestamps, barcode info, email, geolocation and subject code.

There is an `onChange` trigger that creates a timestamp and inserts it into a column, in a sheet named with the subject code (ICTE4115).

#### The problem

> When I turn the attendance "ON" so that students can mark their attendance, many try to do it at the same time especially during the first few minutes. My code works fine but in some cases the `onChange` trigger does not work and the input does not get inserted into to the Google Sheet. It may happen due to network issues. Not sure whether LOCK services work at all. What can I do?

My code is as follows:

```js
function autoConvert(e) {
  try {
    LockService.getScriptLock().waitLock(2000);
    var ss = e.source;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var key = sh.getName();
    var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();

    if (
      key.indexOf("0") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("1") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("2") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("3") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("4") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("5") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("6") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("7") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("8") > -1 ||
      key.indexOf("9") > -1
    ) {
      if (lastRow > 10) {
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 9, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 9, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 8, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 8, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 7, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 7, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 6, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 6, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 5, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 5, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 4, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 4, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 3, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 3, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 2, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 2, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 1, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow - 1, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        sh.getRange(lastRow, 6).setValue(key);
        sh.getRange(lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
      } else {
        for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
          sh.getRange(i, 6).setValue(key);
          sh.getRange(i, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        }
      }
    }
    LockService.getScriptLock().releaseLock();
  } catch (e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760530) with triggers.

*Make sure to "star" the issue to let Google Developers know that this affects you.*

### The problem:

If many edits happen in quick succession (<500ms - at least in my tests) to the sheet, then trigger functions will get "lost". This seems like what you are experiencing. Google Cloud Console Logging confirms this, as it registers no errors, just the trigger functions that have successfully been executed.

### Possible Solution:

#### Web App

Depending on the number of students, you can try setting up an Apps Script [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). This could, for example, involve your Android app making a POST request to the web app. Your web app would need a `doPost` function that would edit the Google Sheet based on the parameters in the POST request.

There can only be 30 simultaneous connections to the web app, as referenced by the Google [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Yet this should be a big improvement on triggers, which, AFAIK, can only queue 2 triggers. That said, once the `onEdit` triggers have started executing, then many more can run in parallel.

Comment: it is onChange trigger, not onEdit.

Comment: It will have a very similar, if not identical behavior to `onEdit` in this respect.

Comment: Interesting that the issue is reopened after a "won't fix".  Maybe there's hope after all.